# Problem while building a custom app with zoom SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, zoom-sdk

I am trying to integrate Zoom SDK in my app. I was following steps provided by the documentation here. I imported both the .arr modules i.e., in commonlibs and mobile rtc then I added required library as dependencies from project structure -> dependencies -> app -> + -> commonlib and mobilertc

These are the dependencies in my `build.gradle (:app)`

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.0.2'

    implementation project(':commonlib')
    implementation project(':mobilertc')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.6'
    implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.16.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.16.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

}
```

and tried

- sync project from gradle file
- invalidate and restart
- reload all from the disk
- clean project rebuild project

and still getting this error

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

   > Could not resolve project :commonlib.
     Required by:

         project :app

      > No matching configuration of project :commonlib was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
   > Could not resolve project :mobilertc.

     Required by:

         project :app

      > No matching configuration of project :mobilertc was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 
'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' but:

          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Looks like you have not imported the libraries properly. You need to go through the documentation again and see where you messed up.

Comment: Which is the content of the build.gradle files inside commonlib and mobilertc modules?

Comment: Which is the content of your settings.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to verify if the java modules are properly added to your project.

```
Project
|
|-- commonlib 
|
|-- mobilertc
|
|-- App
```

Then you have to change the dependencies definition (adding "path:") in the App gradle file:

```
implementation project(path: ':mobilertc')
implementation project(path: ':commonlib')
```

and specifying the proper configuration

```
implementation project(path: ':mobilertc', configuration: 'default')
implementation project(path: ':commonlib', configuration: 'default')
```